How to diagnose: WireGuard unstable communication when an Android device is in the VPN tunnel?
I installed WireGuard in Ubuntu VPS. I connect from Android to the tunnel but it does not allow me to pass traffic.
My /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
root@ghes092i:~# wg show
interface: wg0
  public key: YI5S37TEipIA7Laxxxxxxxx/keBtMDqq8rdK/5tP6zk=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: c7ypIurXvB+EMCtUDFkd6i0HmPz43FtXCtqTHeo0rnk=
  endpoint: 186.95.125.228:29733
  allowed ips: 192.168.1.108/32
  latest handshake: 47 seconds ago
  transfer: 781.22 KiB received, 8.55 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds

WireGuard client Android config:
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.1.108/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = YI4QzKm+IRami=0qlXbSawe0R15nRl5Ug04PuHHQOdwqWOm1g=

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 154.xxx.xx.xxx:51820
PublicKey = YI5S37TEipIA7Laxxxxxxxx/keBtMDqq8rdK/5tP6zk=

WireGuard log results:
[  +6.741685] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[  +0.000005] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[  +0.000255] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 28 destroyed for peer 1
[  +0.000002] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 31 created for peer 1
[ +10.316738] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[ +10.239951] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[ +11.007913] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[Aug18 08:51] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[ +10.751976] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[ +10.047964] device eth0 left promiscuous mode
[  +0.447886] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[ +10.971777] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[  +0.000004] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[  +0.000964] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 30 destroyed for peer 1
[  +0.000016] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 32 created for peer 1
[ +10.275094] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[Aug18 08:52] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[ +10.751923] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)
[ +10.751924] wireguard: wg0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 1 (186.95.125.228:29733)

When the Android device is in the VPN tunnel don't get internet connection.
How can I solve this?

Update: The content of /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf:
root@ghes092i:/etc/wireguard# cat wg0.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = cFmbizFqYHLSJkWfOEjPlbZBXxWherE1YwRqhCmLrHE=

[Peer]
PublicKey = c7ypIurXvB+EMCtUDFkd6i0HmPz43FtXCtqTHeo0rnk=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.108/32
Endpoint = 186.95.125.228:29733
PersistentKeepalive = 25

wq-quick status:
root@ghes092i:/etc/wireguard# systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.service
● wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard VPN tunnel for wg0
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2024-08-18 08:10:29 CST; 3h 14min ago
   Main PID: 439 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2340)
     Memory: 0B
        CPU: 0
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-wg\x2dquick.slice/wg-quick@wg0.service

iptables rules:
root@ghes092i:/etc/wireguard# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i {interface} -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT


added

iptables -t nat -L -n -v:
root@ghes092i:/etc/wireguard# iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0


My /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf - wrong, that's the output of wg command - there's more that would need to be in wg0.conf for yo to get "internet connection" via the tunnel

How can I make an "internet connection" through the tunnel?
What kind of config am I missing in the "wg0.conf" Any help?
¡Thanks for comment!.

As I implied in the first comment, what is the content of wg0.conf? Without seeing that, how can anyone know what is missing? i.e. you'll need some NAT going on for a start - sure, that doesn't have to be in wg0.conf, but then, you'll need to show how you are performing NAT

I just updated the post, and added the contents of wg0.conf. Thanks.

Are you using wg-quick to bring the wg0 interface up and down?

You'll want to add
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE


edit: you may also need

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT

To wg0.conf - where eth0 may be something else, i.e. it's your server's ethernet interface name
Alternatively, you could
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

or
nft 'add rule ip nat POSTROUTING oifname "eth0" counter masquerade'

(and make it permanent the usual ways) - then you don't need any PostUp / PostDown settings in wg0.conf

Hi, thanks for answering!
I have added the lines postup and postdown to the wg0.conf file
also the command
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
However, I still have no internet connection inside the tunnel.
Any help? Is there anything I need to configure?
I added my list of iptables rules in the question for more info.

@SebastianLinux please see edit at top of answer

Thank you so much for your reply, I still have no internet connection inside the tunnel. I have added the new postup and postdown
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
and I edited the question showing the result of iptables -t nat -L -n -v, iptable -S and the wg0.con file
